# Recommended database and orm for a "Windows Store" app

Tags: windows, sqlite, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

We are having an internal debate on our team on whether SQLite is the right database to go with for our "Windows Store" application. My team members claim that SQLite is not threadsafe and that our app will perform poorly and be problematic.

Scouring the net I see lots of references to SQLite and I don't see anyone complaining about threading issues even though by nature SQLite is not thread safe. I don't read anyone recommending other types of databases outside of SQLite.

Also, since SQLite is not thread safe, what is the recommended pattern to creating a stable data access design?

Comment: Questions for recommended libraries [are off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). In any case, please create separate questions, otherwise you risk having answers that are both correct and wrong at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Your team members are wrong; SQLite [is thread safe](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html), and it's fast because it has very little overhead.

Microsoft [recommends](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/win8devsupport/archive/2013/01/10/using-database-in-windows-store-apps-i.aspx) SQLite for Windows Store apps.